# Customize twitter and fb share button image

Tags: css, facebook, user-interface, twitter

I've this code in my page:

```
<a href="https://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button" data-url="<?php echo $refLink; ?>" data-text="my text data" data-via="testdata" data-lang="it" data-size="large" data-count="none" data-dnt="true">Tweet</a>
<script>!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src="//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document,"script","twitter-wjs");</script>
</div>


<a name="fb_share" type="button" 
share_url="<?php echo $refLink; ?>" id="facebook-share">Facebook</a> 
<script src="http://static.ak.fbcdn.net/connect.php/js/FB.Share" type="text/javascript">
</script>
```

Which display default buttons (twitter button with a gradient and fb share blue icon), but now I'd like to have simply two gray background, without those images... how can I customize them?

I tried customizing the CSS using their selectors, but the image always override my css `background-color`.

Answer (score 0):

set the css opacity property for the #facebook-share div to 0, then place another div around it with the proper background-color.

eg.

```
<div id="fb-wrap"><a name="fb_share" type="button" 
share_url="<?php echo $refLink; ?>" id="facebook-share">Facebook</a></div>

css:
#fb-wrap{
  background-color: #foo;
}
#facebook-share{
  opacity: 0;
}
```

of course, you could use a background-image on the wrapper div and use whatever image you like for the button.

Comment: Thansk, what about twitter one?